# microsoft keyboard preventing double space

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I got a new microsoft natural keyboard and didn't change anything else on my computer running Win10 (I had the same or a very, very similar keyboard before). It works fine with one exception: When I hit the space bar twice, it only prints one space. This is not an issue of a specific program, it happens everywhere where I can type text. It happens for no other keys.

Since I only changed hardware, does that mean I can't change this with any settings in Win10?

EDIT: Since the question is hard to understand, this is my issue rephrased: I hit the space bar twice fast and it only prints one space. How can I change it so it types 2 spaces? I want the behaviour that I had on all the dozens of keyboards I used before.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Did you try multiple keywords?

Comment: my old keyboard worked fine. Just the new one has this behaviour.

Comment: What happens if you type 3 or 4 blanks?

Comment: it seems to only depend on the time. When I'm fast, I can hit the space bar 3 or 4 times and I only get 1 space.

Comment: Is your keyboard the 3000 model or 4000 or else?

Comment: it's the 4000. And from what it looks, the one I had before was also the 4000. I can still plug it in and it works fine. Just the new one having this issue.

Comment: This sounds like they made the debouncer overaggressive.  That or you accidentally turned on 'Filter Keys' (check the Ease of Access section of the Settings app for info on that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a firmware update for the Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 that can be found
[in here](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/b2m-00012#techspecs-connect).
Try it in case it's a faulty firmware.

Otherwise, I suggest to have it replaced.
If this also happens with the replacement, then it's a new "feature" for the latest model.

Comment: new drivers didn't help. I'm asking on microsoft forum now. If this doesn't help, then replacement is probably the only solution. thanks